# Strange behavior occuring with msgsnd/msgrcv

Tags: c, linux, ipc

I have two different program :

The first one, basically keep calling `msgrcv` on a message queue in an infinite loop and prints whenever it receives something, in C++ :

```
//foo1.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

typedef struct MessageBuffer {
        long mtype;
        char mtext[255];
} MessageBuffer;

int main() {
    key_t key = ftok("/tmp/toto1", 'b');
    int messageQueue = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT|0666);
    while (true) {
        MessageBuffer message;
        int ret = -1;
        while(ret < 0) {
            usleep(1000000);
            ret = msgrcv(messageQueue, (void*) (&message), sizeof(MessageBuffer)-sizeof(long), 0, 0);
        }
        std::cout << "message is:" << message.mtext << std::endl;
        std::cout << "ret is:" << ret << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with : `g++ foo1.cpp -o foo1`

The other one simply sends a message to the same message queue thanks to `msgsnd`, in C:

```
//foo2.c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct MessageBuffer {
        long mtype;
        char mtext[255];
} MessageBuffer;

int main() {
    key_t key = ftok("/tmp/toto1", 'b');
    int messageQueue = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT|0666);
    MessageBuffer messageToSend;
    //MessageBuffer anOtherMessage; <- problem is here
    strcpy(messageToSend.mtext, "foo message");
    msgsnd(messageQueue, (void*) (&messageToSend), sizeof(MessageBuffer)-sizeof(long), 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with : `gcc foo2.cpp -o foo2`

As it is, everything works fine, I can see in the console of foo1 that it received the message sent by foo2. But if I uncomment the line in foo2.c, it doesn't work anymore, foo1 doesn't receive any message.

Does anyone have an explanation for this ?

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.
gcc and g++ 4.6.3

Comment: `sizeof(MessageBuffer)` counts padding bytes.

Comment: could you provide little more details on what is not working?  the receiver is not getting the data? the size of data you sending is always same, so that is unlikely an issue.

Comment: You might want to explain what exactly "it doesn't work" means.

Comment: Just did, guys, sorry. My brain is melting right now.

Comment: What's the return value from `msgsnd()`?  You aren't checking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to check your return values and to initialise `mtype` (which must be positive).
The failure to initialise `mtype` means that the behaviour of your program is undefined in both cases.
(It is probably non-positive *by chance* when you declare another variable.)

You're also passing too large a size to the function.

This should work:

```
MessageBuffer messageToSend = {1};
MessageBuffer anOtherMessage = {1};
strcpy(messageToSend.mtext, "foo message");
int result = msgsnd(messageQueue, &messageToSend, sizeof(messageToSend.mtext), 0);
if (result < 0)
{
    /* Handle the error. */
}
```